# Hibernate Relational one to many Mapping Issue

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a issue regarding one to many mapping in hibernate 4.x and I am using mysql5.6.

First Let show you my 2 entities,
first user entity,

```
package com.project.entities;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="UserBookingEntryTable")
public class UserBookingEntryClass {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int uid;
    private String ubmobile_no;
    private String ubname;
    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},mappedBy="user")
    private Collection<BookingServicesClass> bookings=new ArrayList<BookingServicesClass>();


    public Collection<BookingServicesClass> getBookings() {
        return bookings;
    }
    public void setBookings(Collection<BookingServicesClass> bookings) {
        this.bookings = bookings;
    }
    public int getUid() {
        return uid;
    }
    public void setUid(int uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }




    public String getUbmobile_no() {
        return ubmobile_no;
    }
    public void setUbmobile_no(String ubmobile_no) {
        this.ubmobile_no = ubmobile_no;
    }
    public String getUbname() {
        return ubname;
    }
    public void setUbname(String ubname) {
        this.ubname = ubname;
    }





}
```

Second Entity -Booking Class

```
package com.project.entities;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "BookingServiceTable")
public class BookingServicesClass {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int booking_id;

    private String first_name;

    private String last_name;

    private String mobile;

    private String location;

    private String booking_address;

    private String booking_type;

    private String landmark;
    private int booking_pincode;
    private Date booking_date;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="usid")
    private UserBookingEntryClass user;
    public Integer getBooking_id() {
        return booking_id;
    }

    public void setBooking_id(Integer booking_id) {
        this.booking_id = booking_id;
    }

    public String getFirst_name() {
        return first_name;
    }

    public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
    }

    public String getLast_name() {
        return last_name;
    }

    public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
        this.last_name = last_name;
    }

    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getBooking_address() {
        return booking_address;
    }

    public void setBooking_address(String booking_address) {
        this.booking_address = booking_address;
    }

    public String getLandmark() {
        return landmark;
    }

    public void setLandmark(String landmark) {
        this.landmark = landmark;
    }

    public Integer getBooking_pincode() {
        return booking_pincode;
    }

    public void setBooking_pincode(Integer booking_pincode) {
        this.booking_pincode = booking_pincode;
    }

    public Date getBooking_date() {
        return booking_date;
    }

    public void setBooking_date(Date booking_date) {
        this.booking_date = booking_date;
    }

    public String getBooking_type() {
        return booking_type;
    }

    public void setBooking_type(String booking_type) {
        this.booking_type = booking_type;
    }

    public UserBookingEntryClass getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(UserBookingEntryClass user) {
        this.user = user;
    }


}

    // to add booking from a user:
    public String addService(String fname, String lname, String mob,
            String ser, String loc, String add, String lm, int pc, String bd) {
        String res = "failure";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        Date convertedCurrentDate = null;

        try {
            convertedCurrentDate = sdf.parse(bd);
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        BookingServicesClass bs = new BookingServicesClass();
        UserBookingEntryClass ubs = new UserBookingEntryClass();
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

        session.beginTransaction();
        System.out.println("dddd");
        try {


            **//userid is auto generated**
            ubs.setUbmobile_no(mob);
            ubs.setUbname((fname + " " + lname));
            // bs.setBid(1);
            bs.setFirst_name(fname);
            bs.setLast_name(lname);
            bs.setMobile(mob);
            bs.setLocation(loc);
            bs.setBooking_type(ser);
            bs.setBooking_address(add);
            bs.setLandmark(lm);
            bs.setBooking_pincode(pc);
            bs.setBooking_date(convertedCurrentDate);
            bs.setUser(ubs);
            session.save(ubs);
            session.save(bs);

            // Commit the transaction
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            /*session.close();*/
            res = "success";
            System.out.println("ajax");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
            res = "failure";
            // success=false;
        }

        return res;
    }
```

---

Now the issue is that one user can do more than one booking.
So the code create a foreign key in booking table which is users key who is booking.
but when the one user books more than one booking the Unique constraint Error is given.
So i made the userid auto genrate which is not according to my needs,
becuase if same user books two booking then userid should be same but when i do this it gives me unique constraint error.

Please  tell how should I implement it.

Thanks

Comment: Just to make sure: at the commented line "// bs.setBid(1);", are you setting dynamic values at each iteration of your method, or are you keeping the 1 value everytime you call it?

Comment: I have given the solution, check and let me know.

Comment: @bonifaco,See the userid is key of user table then in booking table one column is created uid,but if the same user adds the new booking the unique constraints is being generated, becoz if same user was the I'd will be same.

Answer (score 1):

First thing - id of User should not be auto generated, maybe the mobilenumber which will definitely be unique should be the identifier

Second thing - When you add the booking you will check if the user exists , if it exists add the booking to the user ,otherwise create the user and add the bookings, and then commit the user.

Try these and let me know.

```
BookingServicesClass  booking = new BookingServicesClass ()
if(ubmobile_no!=null) {
    UserBookingEntryClass user= session.get(UserBookingEntryClass .class, ubmobile_no);
    if (user!= null) {
          booking.setUser(user);
          user.getBookings().add(booking);
       } else {
          //do nothing
       }
   }
```

Comment: ,can u please elaborate how I can check if the user exist? Demo code if any

Comment: ,Thanks your idea worked for me,but can you tell what were was i goin wrong.

Comment: Although I have posted most of the points observed in your code earlier,however I can tell  what was going wrong if you update what you finally did, so that we can compare. Also if my post was helpful to you in answering correctly , please accept it as a correct answer.